# Java Convert multiple arraylists to 1 JSON

Tags: java, json, arraylist

I have a question. I have an `ArrayList` with objects named: `Candlestick`.
The class Candlestick looks like this:

```
public class Candlestick {

    private long MainKey;
    private String Market;
    private String Coin;
    private String Period;
    private double Open;
    private double High;
    private double Low;
    private double Close;

    public String getMarket() {
        return Market;
    }

    public String getCoin() {
        return Coin;
    }

    public String getPeriod() {
        return Period;
    }
}
```

Now I want to create JSON that looks like this:

```
{
   "USDT":{
      "BTC":{
         "5m":[
            {
               "MainKey":1,
               "Open":3000,
               "Close":3100,
               "High":3100,
               "Low":2900
            },
            {
               "MainKey":2,
               "Open":3000,
               "Close":3100,
               "High":3100,
               "Low":2900
            }
         ],
         "1h":[
            {
               "MainKey":1,
               "Open":3000,
               "Close":3100,
               "High":3100,
               "Low":2900
            },
            {
               "MainKey":2,
               "Open":3000,
               "Close":3100,
               "High":3100,
               "Low":2900
            }
         ],
         "3h":[
            {
               "MainKey":1,
               "Open":3000,
               "Close":3100,
               "High":3100,
               "Low":2900
            },
            {
               "MainKey":2,
               "Open":3000,
               "Close":3100,
               "High":3100,
               "Low":2900
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

To do that, I did the following in Java:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, ArrayList<Candlestick>>>> candles = new HashMap<>();

for (Candlestick candlestick : simCandlestickList) {
    ArrayList<Candlestick> validCandlesticks = new ArrayList<>();
    System.out.println("Market: " + candlestick.getMarket());
    System.out.println("Coin: " + candlestick.getCoin());
    System.out.println("Period: " + candlestick.getPeriod());
    candles.put(candlestick.getMarket(), Map.of(candlestick.getCoin(), Map.of(candlestick.getPeriod(), simCandlestickList)));
}
```

This gives me almost the result I want, except for 1 thing... The object in simCandlestickList doesn't get printed the way it should:

```
{
   "USDT":{
      "BTC":{
         "1m":[
            com.company.Candlestick@942a29c,
            com.company.Candlestick@1ed6388a,
            com.company.Candlestick@5a45133e,
            com.company.Candlestick@534a5a98,
            com.company.Candlestick@4f80542f
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Now how can I print every attribute of Candlestick inside the array? It doesn't matter if the coin, market and period is in there again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that you would either need to override the toString() method of the Candlestick class or use a library like [Jackson Databind](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.12.1) to serialize the data as json. With Jackson's ObjectMapper your code would look like this:

```html
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, List<Candlestick>>>> candles = new HashMap<>();
for (Candlestick candlestick : simCandlestickList) {
    ArrayList<Candlestick> validCandlesticks = new ArrayList<>();
    System.out.println("Market: " + candlestick.getMarket());
    System.out.println("Coin: " + candlestick.getCoin());
    System.out.println("Period: " + candlestick.getPeriod());
    candles.put(candlestick.getMarket(), Map.of(candlestick.getCoin(), Map.of(candlestick.getPeriod(), jsonList)));
}
System.out.println(objectMapper.writer().writeValueAsString(candles));
```

EDIT1: Changed the candles Map to use List instead of ArrayList
EDIT2: Print the whole Map with ObjectMapper instead of writing the Candlestick array as string

Comment: `no instance(s) of type variable(s) exist so that List<String> conforms to ArrayList<String> inference variable V has incompatible bounds: equality constraints: ArrayList<String> lower bounds: List<String>`???

Comment: Use List instead of ArrayList in the Map - it's a good practice to use interfaces instead of concrete implementations

Comment: I get a lot of dashes in my JSON, is this a problem or can I leave it like that? Here is a part of the JSON: `"coin\\\":\\\"BTC\\\",\\\"market\\\":\\\"USDT\\\",\\\"close\\\":3685.91,`

Comment: `JSONObject json =  new JSONObject(candles);
System.out.printf( "JSON: %s", json.toJSONString());`

Comment: I edited the code snippet, this should do it. In short, instead of trying to use a List<String> for the Candlesticks, I just print the whole map with ObjectMapper. You're using JsonObject and that's why the output that you got was escaped.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to gson or Jackson lib to convert your java object into JSON which puts all your class members into key value pairs.

Else you can just use Map and populate that map using each of class attribute and value manually for each of Java object.